# Save WizardPage Settings with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, wizard

I created a Wizard with a wizardpage for exporting Files in a Folder.
How can I save the last selected folder in my wizard?
So if the user opens the wizard again, the options which he selected the last time should be written in there.

Comment: serialize the settings object http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try following:

```
 1. Retrieve DialogSettings object.
 2. Find your section. If it is null, create it.
 3. Use it to store/load related information.

IDialogSettings settings = WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getDialogSettings();
IDialogSettings section = settings.getSection("your_section_name");
if (section == null) {
   section = settings.addNewSection("your_section_name");
} 
String lastSelectedFolder = section.get("your_last_selected_folder_key");
```